# Matlab uicontrol function modification

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I'm working on a project in which some parts are concerned with TicTacToe game. I have the tictactoe.m file and would like to change the code so that the player's selection would be applied by a function's output, say,RESULT parameter rather than clicking on the screen by the user himself. the uicontrol part of my code is as follows. How may I control the game by another function's output instead of pushbutton style?

```
function B = buttons
% Initialize push buttons and text.
clf
shg
B = zeros(3,3);
M = magic(3); % strategical approach and equivalent game for TicTacToe game.
for k = 1:9
[i,j] = find(k == M);
B(i,j) = uicontrol('style','pushbutton','units','normal', ...
  'fontsize',16,'callback','tictactoe(''green'')');
end
uicontrol('style','text','units','normal','pos',[0.30 0.82 0.40 0.10], ...
'fontsize',20,'background',get(gcf,'color'),'tag','toptext');

uicontrol('style','text','units','normal','pos',[0.20 0.72 0.60 0.10], ...
'fontsize',10,'background',get(gcf,'color'),'tag','toptext','string', ...
['Pick single digit numbers.  Each digit can be chosen only once. ' ...
'Generate a total of 15 using exactly three digits.'])

uicontrol('style','pushbutton','units','normal','string','Game', ...
'fontsize',12,'position',[.23 .12 .15 .07], ...
'callback','tictactoe(''game'')');

uicontrol('style','pushbutton','units','normal','string','Start', ...
'fontsize',12,'position',[.43 .12 .15 .07], ...
'callback','tictactoe(''start'')');

uicontrol('style','pushbutton','units','normal','string','Exit', ...
'fontsize',12,'position',[.63 .12 .15 .07], ...
'callback','tictactoe(''exit'')');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the push button is doing is executing a callback command. In this case the pushbutton 'Start' is calling

```
tictactoe('start')
```

So you can get another function to start the came by calling the same function, you will have to look at the function 'tictactoe' because it will need another couple of inputs, the pushbutton uicontrol automatically adds in the extra inputs, objects handles etc.